# What would this equation be simplified to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What would the result of $4\sqrt x$ multiplied by $18x^2-12$? Would it just be $18x^{10/4}$?

Comment: Do you mean $4\sqrt x(18x^2-12)$?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 2):

If by *simplify* you mean *multiply out*,

$$4\sqrt x\left(18x^2-12\right)=4x^{1/2}\left(18x^2-12\right)=72x^{5/2}-48x^{1/2}\;,$$

If, on the other hand, you mean *factor as completely as possible*,

$$4\sqrt x\left(18x^2-12\right)=24\sqrt x\left(3x^2-2\right)=24\sqrt x\left(\sqrt3 x-\sqrt2\right)\left(\sqrt 3x+\sqrt2\right)\;.$$

There is no way to reduce it to a single term with a single power of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$4\sqrt x(18x^2-12)=\begin{cases}72\sqrt x\,x^2-48\sqrt x=72x^{5/2}-48x^{1/2}\\{}\\24\sqrt x(3x^2-2)\end{cases}$$

...so no: it is not what you thought it is.

Answer (score 1):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2a%28x%5E0.5%29%2a%2818%2ax%2ax-12%29) shows the same. The roots of your expression are $0$ and $+/-$ $\sqrt{2/3}$